# AWS Cognito & SMS mfa from backend

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to implement AWS Cognito MFA on a backend built in PHP. In particular we are having problems with device tracking, following this documentation: https://repost.aws/it/knowledge-center/cognito-user-pool-remembered-devices.

The problem is that after responding to the `SMS_MFA` challenge, I try to call `confirmDevice` like this:

```php
$srp = new AwsCognitoIdentitySRP($this->client, $this->appClientId, $this->userPoolId);
$challengeResponses = ["SMS_MFA_CODE" => $code, "USERNAME" => $username];

$response = $this->client->respondToAuthChallenge([
    "ChallengeName"      => "SMS_MFA",
    "ChallengeResponses" => $challengeResponses,
    'Session'            => $session,
    'ClientId'           => $this->appClientId,
    'UserPoolId'         => $this->userPoolId,
]);

$metadata = $response->get('AuthenticationResult');

$accessToken = $metadata['AccessToken'] ? ? null;
$deviceGroupKey = $metadata['NewDeviceMetadata']['DeviceGroupKey'] ? ? null;
$deviceKey = $metadata['NewDeviceMetadata']['DeviceKey'] ? ? null;

$passSalt = $srp->getDeviceSecretVerifierConfig($deviceGroupKey, $deviceKey);
$result = $this->client->confirmDevice([
    'AccessToken' => $accessToken, 
    'DeviceKey' => $deviceKey, 
    'DeviceName' => "My personal location" . " Auto", 
    'DeviceSecretVerifierConfig' => [
         'PasswordVerifier' => $passSalt['PasswordVerifier'], 
         'Salt' => $passSalt['Salt'], 
    ], 
]);
```

but the client returns the error "Invalid device key given.". does anyone have ideas on how to fix this?

`AwsCognitoIdentitySRP` is this library here https://gist.github.com/jenky/a4465f73adf90206b3e98c3d36a3be4f. The code for getDeviceSecretVerifierConfig is this https://gist.github.com/jenky/a4465f73adf90206b3e98c3d36a3be4f?permalink_comment_id=4624736#gistcomment-4624736.